# Compare a 3D list with a 4D list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm working with lists, one is a 3D list and the other is a 4D list and I'm trying to compare them, if the inner lists matches then append "True" else append "False" I did something, but it's not exactly working working, so maybe you can help me, this is my code

```
#3D list
list1 = [[[0, 2, 1], [0, 4, 2, 3, 1]], [[0, 4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1]], [[0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]]]

#4D list
list2 = [[[[0, 2, 1], [0, 4, 2, 1]], [[0, 4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1]], [[0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 4, 1]]], 
         [[[0, 2, 1], [0, 4, 2, 3, 1]], [[0, 4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1]], [[0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]]]]

decision = []
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    finaldecision = []
    for k in j:
        if i == k:
            decision.append('True')
        else:
            decision.append('False')
    finaldecision.append(decision)
                
print(finaldecision)

finaldecision = [['False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False']]
```

I want to compare every two elements something like:

```
#From the 3D list               #From the first 3D list of the 4D list
[[0, 2, 1], [0, 4, 2, 3, 1]]    == [[0, 2, 1], [0, 4, 2, 1]]           #False
[[0, 4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1]]    == [[0, 4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 3, 1]]        #True
[[0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]] == [[0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 4, 1]]           #False
```

And then do the same for the next 3D list of the 4D list, this is my desired output.

```
finaldecision = [[False, True, False], [True, True, True]]
```

I do get the number the elements, but the True and False order are not right and also the dimension of the resultant 2D list are not right, any help will be appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
finaldecision = []
for i in list2:
    decision = []
    
    for j in range(len(i)):
        decision.append(i[j] == list1[j]
    finaldecision.append(decision)
```

In the first loop you get both the lists onto the same level and then in the nested loop you compare each element assuming they are the same length.